# mongotemplate aggregation with condition

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection where the documents look like this:

```
{
  _id: "545b9fa0dd5318a4285f7ce7",
  owner: "admin",  
  messages: [
    {
      id: "100",
      status: "sent",
      note: ""
    },
    {
      id: "100",
      status: "pending",
      note: ""
    },
    {
      id: "101",
      status: "sent",
      note: ""
    },
    {
      id: "102",
      status: "sent",
      note: ""
    },
    {
      id: "101",
      status: "done",
      note: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

(This is just a short example, in my case the sub array is very large)

I need to query the collection and get some statistics for a specific document.
So in this example if I query the doucment that has id: "545b9fa0dd5318a4285f7ce7"
I should get this result:

```
{
   sent: 3,
   pending: 1,
   done: 1
}
```

How can I do such aggregation with spring mongotemplate ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this sort of thing you need the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator in the aggregation framework. Spring Data MongoDB does not do that yet, and there are many things lacking from common [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operations that are even only implemented under [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

The issue for tracking implementation of any [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) support is here:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-861

For the rest of the world it looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("545b9fa0dd5318a4285f7ce7") } },
    { "$unwind": "$messages" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "sent": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$mesages.status", "sent" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "pending": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$messages.status", "pending" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "done": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$messages.status", "done" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

To get that sort of thing to work under a mongotemplate aggregation you need a class extending aggregation operations that can be built from a DBObject:

```
public class CustomGroupOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomGroupOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

Then you can define the "$group" as a `DBObject` and implement in the aggregation pipeline:

```
   DBObject myGroup = (DBObject)new BasicDBObject(
        "$group", new BasicDBObject(
            "_id","$_id"
        ).append(
            "sent", new BasicDBObject(
                "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                    "$cond", new Object[]{
                        new BasicDBObject(
                            "$eq", new Object[]{ "$messages.status", "sent"}
                        ),
                        1,
                        0
                    }
                )
            )
        ).append(
            "pending", new BasicDBObject(
                "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                    "$cond", new Object[]{
                        new BasicDBObject(
                            "$eq", new Object[]{ "$messages.status", "pending"}
                        ),
                        1,
                        0
                    }
                )
             )
        ).append(
            "done", new BasicDBObject(
                "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                    "$cond", new Object[]{
                         new BasicDBObject(
                            "$eq", new Object[]{ "$messages.status", "done"}
                         ),
                         1,
                         0
                    }
                 )
            )
        )
     );


   ObjectId myId = new ObjectId("545b9fa0dd5318a4285f7ce7");

   Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
           match(Criteria.where("_id").is(myId)),
           unwind("messges"),
           new CustomGroupOperation(myGroup)
   );
```

That allows you to come up with a pipeline that is basically the same as the shell representation above.

So it would seem that for now, where certain operations and sequences are not supported the best case is to implement a class on the [AgggregationOperation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationOperation.html) interface that can be fed a DBObject or otherwise internally construct one from your own custom methods.

Comment: your solution works great ( only needs to change $status to $messages.status ), I hope mongotemplate would add more aggregation api soon, because this is not very elegant.

Comment: @jacob Sorry, my bad. Typed too quickly. I'll edit for posterity. I re-tagged your question to what I know the "spring-data" maintainers look at on a regular basis. The `$cond` issue has been sitting out there for a while. Complex grouping and grouping `_id` values are "known issues". Some of this is really not that hard to implement as methods. You can always donate time. And I should consider that too.

Comment: @NeilLunn How do I match two conditions? For example I want to match `messages.status=="Done"` and `messages.status2=="Ready"`.

Comment: @NeilLunn please show implementation of `match` and `unwind` methods.

Comment: @NeilLunn I do not find where to specify collection name. Can you please share full code?

Comment: This is the year 2020. Can someone has better solution? I do not want to extend the class. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following aggregation :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $match : { "_id" : ObjectId("545b9fa0dd5318a4285f7ce7") } },
    { $unwind : "$messages" },
    { $group : { "_id" : "$messages.status", "count" : { $sum : 1} } }
)
```

it will give you the count of `status` for which `message` are available, all other `status` count should be consider 0.