# Convert mongo query to Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

How do I write the following mongoDB query in Spring?

```
db.reportData.aggregate([
{ $match : { iecode : {$in:["P110017","P111111"]} } } ,
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$iecode",
        "treatmentArms": { "$first": "$evaluationDTOList" }
    }
},
{ "$unwind": "$treatmentArms" },
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "Package": { 
            "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ 
                   { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Package" ] }, 
                   1, 0
                ] 
            }
        },
        "Behavioral-bias related mechanisms":{
            "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ 
                    { 
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Mechanism" ] },
                            { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismTested1", "Behavioral-bias related mechanisms" ] }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    1, 
                    0 ]
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

My Database name : MyProjects
Collection name : reportData

Please note that I am using spring MongoTemplate.

**Edit**

Here is my code which I tried

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void getIEQuestions(Map<String, List<String>> paramMap){
    System.out.println("get ie questions-------------------------------------------");
    DBCollection projects = getMongoOperations().getCollection("reportData");

    BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();

    List<BasicDBObject> filters = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : paramMap.entrySet()) {
        ArrayList<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
            if (entry.getValue().get(i) != null && entry.getValue().get(i) != "") {
                System.out.println("entry.getValue().get(i): " + entry.getValue().get(i));
                vals.add(entry.getValue().get(i));
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            filters.add(new BasicDBObject(entry.getKey(), new BasicDBObject("$in", vals)));
        }
    }
    andQuery.put("$and", filters);

    //adding all the filters I want to apply
    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", andQuery);

    DBObject groupByIECode = new BasicDBObject("$group",
            new BasicDBObject("_id","$iecode"))
                            .append("treatmentArms",new BasicDBObject("$first","$evaluationDTOList"));

    DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$treatmentArms");



    DBObject finalCalculation = new BasicDBObject("$group",new BasicDBObject("_id",null))
                                .append(
                                        "Package", new BasicDBObject(
                                            "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                                                "$cond", new Object[]{
                                                    new BasicDBObject(
                                                        "$eq", new Object[]{ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Package"}
                                                    ),
                                                    1,
                                                    0
                                                }
                                            )
                                        )
                                    );

    final AggregationOutput output = projects.aggregate(match, groupByIECode, unwind, finalCalculation);

    for (DBObject result1 : output.results()) {
        String totalPackage = (String) result1.get("Package");
        System.out.println("Total package: "+totalPackage);
    }

}
```

It is giving me duplicateMongoKey exception.

Later I find out `$cond` operation is not yet supported by spring mongotemplate from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874376/mongotemplate-aggregation-with-condition)

Comment: Can you please share what is the code you tried? even if it is incorrect, it is fine. Share it first. It shall be reviewed and corrected

Comment: @Nattyk I have added my code.