# Conditional query with spring mongotemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I want to use conditional query.

Here is my **query**

```
db.projects.aggregate([
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$iecode",
        "treatmentArms": { "$first": "$evaluationDTOList" }
    }
},
{ "$unwind": "$treatmentArms" },
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "Package": { 
            "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ 
                   { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Package" ] }, 
                   1, 0
                ] 
            }
        },
        "Constraint-relaxing mechanisms": { 
            "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ 
                    { 
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Mechanism" ] },
                            { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismTested1", "Constraint-relaxing mechanisms" ] }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    1, 
                    0 ]
            }
        },
        "Delivery mechanisms": { 
            "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ 
                    { 
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Mechanism" ] },
                            { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismTested1", "Delivery mechanisms" ] }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    1, 
                    0 ]
            }
        },
        "Other": { 
            "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [ 
                    { 
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Mechanism" ] },
                            { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismTested1", "Other" ] }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    1, 
                    0 ]
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

Here is my **java code**

```
DBObject groupByIECode = new BasicDBObject("$group",
                new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("iecode","$iecode")).append("treatmentArms",new BasicDBObject("$first","$evaluationDTOList")));
        System.out.println("groupByIECode: "+groupByIECode.toString());

        DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$treatmentArms");
        System.out.println("unwind: "+unwind.toString());


        DBObject finalCalculation = new BasicDBObject("$group",new BasicDBObject("_id",null))
                                    .append(
                                            "Package", new BasicDBObject(
                                                "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                                                    "$cond", new Object[]{
                                                        new BasicDBObject(
                                                            "$eq", new Object[]{ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Package"}
                                                        ),
                                                        1,
                                                        0
                                                    }
                                                )
                                            )
                                        );

        System.out.println("finalCalculation: "+finalCalculation);
        final AggregationOutput output = projects.aggregate(match,groupByIECode,unwind,finalCalculation);
```

It gives me `MongoException$DuplicateKey`

Later I found out that `$cond` operator is not supported in `spring mongotemplate`. So how do I implememt this conditional query with `spring mongotemplate`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874376/mongotemplate-aggregation-with-condition.) link has some explanation but it do not shows full implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.basic-concepts), a canonical example for using the Spring Data MongoDB support for the MongoDB Aggregation Framework looks as follows:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    pipelineOP1(),
    pipelineOP2(),
    pipelineOPn()
);

AggregationResults<OutputType> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,
    "INPUT_COLLECTION_NAME", OutputType.class);
List<OutputType> mappedResult = results.getMappedResults();
```

> Note that if you provide an input class as the first parameter to the
>   newAggregation method the MongoTemplate will derive the name of the
>   input collection from this class. Otherwise if you don’t specify
>   an input class you must provide the name of the input collection
>   explicitly. If an input-class and an input-collection is provided the
>   latter takes precedence.

---

For your query, create a workaround that implements the **[AggregationOperation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationOperation.html)** interface to take in a `DBObject` that represents a single group operation in an aggregation pipeline with the **`$cond`** operator:

```
public class GroupAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public GroupAggregationOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

Then implement the `$group` operation as a DBObject in the aggregation pipeline that is the same as the one you have:

```
DBObject operation = (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", null))
    .append(
        "Package", new BasicDBObject(
            "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                "$cond", new Object[]{
                    new BasicDBObject(
                        "$eq", new Object[]{ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Package"}
                    ),
                    1,
                    0
                }
            )
        )
    );
```

which you can then use as:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

GroupAggregationOperation groupOp = new GroupAggregationOperation(operation);
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    group("iecode").first("treatmentArms").as("treatmentArms"),
    unwind("treatmentArms"),
    groupOp 
);
AggregationResults<Entity> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Entity.class); 
List<Entity> entities = results.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: can I get `DBObject` from the `Aggregation` object. Actually I do not have been class(Entity).

Comment: I mean where do I specify the collection name on which I want to fire my query.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince I've updated my answer with the canonical example from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.basic-concepts) which I would encourage you to go through.

Comment: How do I specify more than one condition? LIke `"$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg == Package"` and `"$treatmentArms.mechanism == Mechanism1"`.

Comment: Append another DBObject with the conditions

Comment: Won't I have to use `$and`?

Comment: No. It's only a matter of appending the other `$group` object keys on the existing `DBObject` i.e. `DBObject operation = (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", null)).append("Package", new ...).append("Constraint-relaxing mechanisms", new ...).append("Delivery mechanisms", new ...).append(...`

Comment: Okay. What I did is I made a list of `BasicDBObject` with name `filters`, added all filters in that and used it like `new BasicDBObject("$and",filters)`.